# I don't understand how nodes work in a linked list

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list, python-class

I have a basic understanding of usage of nodes, like `node = node.next`, and `self.head`, and things like

```
node.next = self.head
self.head = new_node
```

to add whatever is in new_node to the beginning of the list.

However, I am confused about how the key logic in the three update methods of the linked list class works (the code where these lines are from is at the bottom):

**In add_update():**

```
new_node.next = node.next
node.next = new_node
```

**In add_before():**

```
prev_node.next = new_node
new_node.next = node
```

**In remove_node():**

```
previous_node.next = node.next
```

For the "add" methods, I am confused about how everything gets linked, and for the "remove" method, I don't understand how the code above has the desired effect of removal.

The code is the following:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.data

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, nodes=None):
        self.head = None
        if nodes is not None:
            node = Node(data=nodes.pop(0))
            self.head = node
            for elem in nodes:
                node.next = Node(data=elem)
                node = node.next

    def __repr__(self):
        node = self.head
        nodes = []
        while node is not None:
            nodes.append(node.data)
            node = node.next
        nodes.append("None")
        return " -> ".join(nodes)

    def __iter__(self):
        node = self.head
        while node is not None:
            yield node
            node = node.next

    def add_after(self, target_node_data, new_node):

        for node in self:
            if node.data == target_node_data:
                new_node.next = node.next
                node.next = new_node
                return

    def add_before(self, target_node_data, new_node):

        if self.head.data == target_node_data:
            return self.add_first(new_node)

        for node in self:
            if node.data == target_node_data:
                prev_node.next = new_node
                new_node.next = node
                return
            prev_node = node

    def remove_node(self, target_node_data):

        if self.head.data == target_node_data:
            self.head = self.head.next
            return

        previous_node = self.head
        for node in self:
            if node.data == target_node_data:
                previous_node.next = node.next
                return
            previous_node = node

llist = LinkedList(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])

print(repr(llist))

llist.add_after('c', Node('1'))

print(repr(llist))

llist.add_before('d', Node('2'))

print(repr(llist))

llist.remove_node('c')

print(repr(llist))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a detailed annotation of the code you have supplied. Hopefully this will provide some insight into the things your question is asking about.

---

The nodes in a linked list look like this, for example:

```
object:        node1        node2        node3       node4       node5
data type:     Node
attributes:
    name:      data
    contents:  'a'          'b'          'c'          'd'        'e'

    name:      next
    contents:  node2        node3        node4        node5      None
```

The linked list object itself looks (in this example) like this:

```
object:        llist
data type:     LinkedList
attributes:
    name:      head
    contents:  node1
```

By convention, the first node of a linked list is known as the `head` of the linked list, and the last node (namely, the node with a `next` attribute equal to null, or `None` in python) is known as the `tail` of the linked list. In our example, `node1` is the head and `node5` is the tail.

Let's look at the key methods in your LinkedList class (`__iter__`, `add_after`, `add_before` and `remove_node`).

**The `__iter__` method:**

```py
    def __iter__(self):
        node = self.head
        while node is not None:
            yield node
            node = node.next
```

This method allows us to use language constructs like `for node in self` to iterate through the nodes in the linked list. In our example:

```
node = self.head           # assigns `node1` object to variable node

while node is not None:    # tests `True`
yield node                 # makes `node1` available to the caller on call #1
node = node.next           # assigns `node2` to variable node

while node is not None:    # tests `True`
yield node                 # makes `node2` available to the caller on call #2
node = node.next           # assigns `node3` to variable node

while node is not None:    # tests `True`
yield node                 # makes `node3` available to the caller on call #3
node = node.next           # assigns `node4` to variable node

while node is not None:    # tests `True`
yield node                 # makes `node4` available to the caller on call #4
node = node.next           # assigns `node5` to variable node

while node is not None:    # tests `True`
yield node                 # makes `node5` available to the caller on call #5
node = node.next           # assigns `None` to variable node

while node is not None:    # tests `False`
```

**The `add_after` method:**

```py
def add_after(self, target_node_data, new_node):

        for node in self:
            if node.data == target_node_data:
                new_node.next = node.next
                node.next = new_node
                return
```

This method finds an existing node whose `data` attribute matches the `target_node_data` arguments and inserts argument `new_node` immediately after (or "downstream" of) the matching node.

Suppose we use it like this for our example:

```py
llist.add_after('c', Node('1'))
```

Then `add_after` would do this:

```py
for node in self:                    # assigns `node1` object to variable node by calling `__iter__`
if node.data == target_node_data:    # node1.data is 'a', target_node_data is 'c', so comparison tests False

for node in self:                    # assigns `node2` object to variable node by calling `__iter__`
if node.data == target_node_data:    # node2.data is 'b', target_node_data is 'c', so comparison tests False

for node in self:                    # assigns `node3` object to variable node by calling `__iter__`
if node.data == target_node_data:    # node3.data is 'c', target_node_data is 'c', so comparison tests True

                                     # we now want to "splice" new_node in place between node and node.next
new_node.next = node.next            # assigns `node4` object (which is referenced by node.next) to new_node.next
node.next = new_node                 # update node.next to now reference new_node
                                     # NOTE: further down in this answer, we will refer to the node object we have added here as node3_1

return                               # the method has finished its work, so it returns without examining any further downstream nodes
```

The nodes in our linked list example now look like this:

```
object:        node1        node2        node3        node3_1     node4       node5
data type:     Node
attributes:
    name:      data
    contents:  'a'          'b'          'c'          '1'         'd'         'e'

    name:      next
    contents:  node2        node3        node3_1      node4       node5       None
```

**The `add_before` method:**

```py
    def add_before(self, target_node_data, new_node):

        if self.head.data == target_node_data:
            return self.add_first(new_node)

        for node in self:
            if node.data == target_node_data:
                prev_node.next = new_node
                new_node.next = node
                return
            prev_node = node
```

This method finds an existing node whose `data` attribute matches the `target_node_data` arguments and inserts argument `new_node` immediately before (or "upstream" of) the matching node.

Suppose we use it like this for our example:

```py
llist.add_before('d', Node('2'))
```

Then `add_before` would do this:

```py
if self.head.data == target_node_data:  # handles an edge case: if head is the node we want to add our node before, we need to update our head attribute
return self.add_first(new_node)         # this method is not shown in your question, but would simply do this: new_node.next = self.head; self.head = new_node
                                        # NOTE: does not apply in our example

for node in self:                       # assigns `node1` object to variable node by calling `__iter__`
if node.data == target_node_data:       # node1.data is 'a', target_node_data is 'd', so comparison tests False
prev_node = node                        # save a reference to the 'node1' object in variable prev_node

for node in self:                       # assigns `node2` object to variable node by calling `__iter__`
if node.data == target_node_data:       # node1.data is 'b', target_node_data is 'd', so comparison tests False
prev_node = node                        # save a reference to the 'node2' object in variable prev_node

for node in self:                       # assigns `node3` object to variable node by calling `__iter__`
if node.data == target_node_data:       # node1.data is 'c', target_node_data is 'd', so comparison tests False
prev_node = node                        # save a reference to the 'node3' object in variable prev_node

for node in self:                       # assigns `node3_1` object to variable node by calling `__iter__`
if node.data == target_node_data:       # node3_1.data is '1', target_node_data is 'd', so comparison tests False
prev_node = node                        # save a reference to the 'node3_1' object in variable prev_node

for node in self:                       # assigns `node4` object to variable node by calling `__iter__`
if node.data == target_node_data:       # node4.data is 'd', target_node_data is 'd', so comparison tests True

                                        # we now want to "splice" new_node in place 
prev_node.next = new_node               # assigns the object referenced by the new_node argument to the next attribute of 'node3_1'
new_node.next = node                    # assigns 'node4' to the next attribute of new_node
                                        # NOTE: further down in this answer, we will refer to the node object we have added here as node3_2

return                                  # the method has finished its work, so it returns without examining any further downstream nodes
```

The nodes in our linked list example now look like this:

```
object:        node1        node2        node3        node3_1     node3_2     node4       node5
data type:     Node
attributes:
    name:      data
    contents:  'a'          'b'          'c'          '1'         '2'         'd'         'e'

    name:      next
    contents:  node2        node3        node3_1      node3_2      node4       node5       None
```

**The `remove_node` method:**

```py
    def remove_node(self, target_node_data):

        if self.head.data == target_node_data:
            self.head = self.head.next
            return

        previous_node = self.head
        for node in self:
            if node.data == target_node_data:
                previous_node.next = node.next
                return
            previous_node = node
```

This method finds an existing node whose `data` attribute matches the `target_node_data` arguments and inserts argument `new_node` immediately before (or "upstream" of) the matching node.

Suppose we use it like this for our example:

```py
llist.remove_node('c')
```

Then `remove_node` would do this:

```py
if self.head.data == target_node_data:  # handles an edge case: if head is the node we want to remove, we need to update our head attribute
self.head = self.head.next              # simply assign self.head.next to the attribute self.head
                                        # NOTE: does not apply in our example

previous_node = self.head               # save a reference to the 'node1' object in variable previous_node

for node in self:                       # assigns `node1` object to variable node by calling `__iter__`
if node.data == target_node_data:       # node1.data is 'a', target_node_data is 'c', so comparison tests False
previous_node = node                    # save a reference to the 'node1' object in variable previous_node

for node in self:                       # assigns `node2` object to variable node by calling `__iter__`
if node.data == target_node_data:       # node2.data is 'b', target_node_data is 'c', so comparison tests False
previous_node = node                    # save a reference to the 'node2' object in variable previous_node

for node in self:                       # assigns `node3` object to variable node by calling `__iter__`
if node.data == target_node_data:       # node3.data is 'c', target_node_data is 'c', so comparison tests True
previous_node.next = node.next          # update the next attribute of 'node2' to refer to the next attribute of 'node3', which is 'node3_1'
                                        # NOTE: the object 'node3' is no longer referenced by the next attribute of any nodes in our linked list, which means it has now been removed

return                                  # the method has finished its work, so it returns without examining any further downstream nodes
```

The nodes in our linked list example now look like this:

```
object:        node1        node2        node3_1     node3_2     node4       node5
data type:     Node
attributes:
    name:      data
    contents:  'a'          'b'          '1'         '2'         'd'         'e'

    name:      next
    contents:  node2        node3_1      node3_2      node4       node5       None
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! It was very confusing at first, but after giving it a lot of thought, it all started to make sense. I think what confused me most, is I didn't realise the difference between changing the object a variable holds, and an attribute of the said object, but thanks to your explanation it all makes sense! Thank you again, and have a nice day.